# error when run rosbridge

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I tried to run rosbridge after following instruction: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite/Tutorials/DevelopingRosbridge
and got below error. Please help me. I am running ROS on virtual machine with 64bit Indigo.

```
viki@c3po:~/Documents/ROS_Packages$ roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
... logging to /home/viki/.ros/log/46468e80-9263-11e5-9948-080027b46cdd/roslaunch-c3po-3640.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://c3po:41824/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosbridge_websocket/address: 
 * /rosbridge_websocket/authenticate: False
 * /rosbridge_websocket/port: 9090
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.8

NODES
  /
    rosapi (rosapi/rosapi_node)
    rosbridge_websocket (rosbridge_server/rosbridge_websocket)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rosbridge_websocket-1]: started with pid [3658]
process[rosapi-2]: started with pid [3659]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viki/Documents/ROS_Packages/src/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_server/scripts/rosbridge_websocket", line 43, in <module>
    from rosbridge_server import RosbridgeWebSocket
  File "/home/viki/Documents/ROS_Packages/src/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_server/src/rosbridge_server/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from websocket_handler import RosbridgeWebSocket
  File "/home/viki/Documents/ROS_Packages/src/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_server/src/rosbridge_server/websocket_handler.py", line 42, in <module>
    from rosbridge_library.rosbridge_protocol import RosbridgeProtocol
  File "/home/viki/Documents/ROS_Packages/src/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_library/src/rosbridge_library/rosbridge_protocol.py", line 33, in <module>
    from rosbridge_library.protocol import Protocol
  File "/home/viki/Documents/ROS_Packages/src/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_library/src/rosbridge_library/protocol.py", line 35, in <module>
    import bson
ImportError: No module named bson
[rosbridge_websocket-1] process has died [pid 3658, exit code 1, cmd /home/viki/Documents/ROS_Packages/src/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_server/scripts/rosbridge_websocket __name:=rosbridge_websocket __log:=/home/viki/.ros/log/46468e80-9263-11e5-9948-080027b46cdd/rosbridge_websocket-1.log].
log file: /home/viki/.ros/log/46468e80-9263-11e5-9948-080027b46cdd/rosbridge_websocket-1*.log
```

I have to press Ctrl-C to continue. I have just started leaning ROS.

Regards,
Thang Nguyen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221426/error-when-run-rosbridge/) by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you tell us why you installed `rosbridge_suite` from source (ie: `git clone ..`) instead of `sudo apt-get install ros-$distro-rosbridge-suite`? Do you want to *use* `rosbridge` or *develop* for it?

If you only want to use it, please throw away your source checkout and just `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosbridge-suite` in a terminal. That should install everything for you.

> ```
>     import bson
> ```

```
ImportError: No module named bson
```

This basically tells you that you didn't install all required dependencies before trying to use the package(s). In a source install, *you* are responsible for making sure you've checked the requirements. This is also not ROS specific, but basic Python.

Installation of pre-built binaries will take care of dependency resolution and setup.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-11-24**:
And if you need the installation from source `rosdep install` will be your weapon of choice.

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2015-11-24**:
You can run `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y` from your catkin_workspace directory.

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2015-11-25**:
Should I install rosdep first before use it? (follow link: http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep)
I got error when try your command
viki@c3po:~/Documents/ROS_Packages$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resol

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2015-11-25**:
to system dependencies:
rosbridge_library: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [python-bson]

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2015-11-25**:
I installed the suite and rosbridge work fine now. But to gain knowledge, I still want to know the answer for my question in above comment.
Thank you very much for your help.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-11-25**:
You could add the `-r` option to your `rosdep` call. This will continue after errors. Then do again `catkin_make` then again `rosdep install`. Try both commands till it works.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-25**:
@BennyRe: no, that is not going to help here.
@Thang Nguyen: please try a `rosdep update` and then try again. `python-bson` is definitely in the [rosdep rules](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml#L228-L231), so it should work.